# Google Sheets Script - changing the contents of a cell based on a given condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to set up a submit button that changes the contents of a cell based on the selection the user makes on another sheet.
[ Something along the lines of getrange(match()).setvalue() ]

I can't seem to find a way to identify the correct range with the script.  Attached is my dummy spreadsheet.

Here's what I would like to happen: The user will select answers to question 1 and 2 on the 'List' sheet (cells A2 and B2 with cell validation).  Once the user clicks the SUBMIT button on the 'List' sheet, the associated cell contents on the 'Master' sheet change to FALSE.

Currently, the 'List' sheet uses a timestamp in column C to populate the 'Database' Sheet with the options for validation.  The script for making the submit button work has eluded me.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JE3DWK7L0JKIt4XixfGjvA6qus5MlTMy9_hrqTRVOWg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your spreadsheet and added some code:

```
function forButton() {
  //Logger.log('it ran!'); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master');

  var inputValues = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 3).getValues();
  var secondInput = inputValues[0][1];
  var allColumnTwoVals = masterSheet.getRange(2, 2, 6, 1).getValues();
  allColumnTwoVals = allColumnTwoVals.join().split(",");

  Logger.log('secondInput: ' + secondInput);
  Logger.log('allColumnTwoVals: ' + allColumnTwoVals);

  var foundRow = allColumnTwoVals.indexOf(secondInput);
  masterSheet.getRange(foundRow+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue("TRUE");

  masterSheet.activate();
  Browser.msgBox("New Values Just Entered!", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO_CANCEL);
};
```

I assigned a script to the image of the button?

[image: Assign Script]

Comment: This is very close!!!! Instead of adding a row to the bottom that has the input values, I'm looking for the current values to changes.  The range is not another row on the bottom, the range is the current master list.

Comment: I also really like the browser buttons!  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Okay, so you want the currently filled cells to be overwritten with new information?

Comment: yes, that's correct.  In my spreadsheet, if AAX was selected for question 2 -> then cell C2 on the 'Master' sheet would change from FALSE to TRUE.  This would hold for whatever selection is made on the 'List' sheet.

Comment: See updated answer.  I tested it, it works.  Please mark answer as correct.